# change variable for && conditions javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, conditional-statements, css-animations

I am trying to make a window scroll function that pops a sidebar out once past a certain point, and then pops it away when going back up past that point, however I don;t want to be able to cue the animation for hiding the sidebar till I have gone past the point once. I tried adding a variable that would change when the first event happens, and then is a conditional && operator in an if else statment

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
var z = 500;
var q = 1;

if (y >= z) {
    menu1.css("animation-play-state", "running");
    menu1.css("animation-direction", "normal");
    menu1.css("animation-fill-mode", "forwards");
    menu1.css("animation-name", "sidemenuanimation");
    q = 2;


}else if (y < z && q == 2){
    menu1.css("animation-name", "sidemenuanimation2");
}

});
```

keyframes:

```
 @keyframes sidemenuanimation {
0% {transform: translateX(0px);}
100% {transform: translateX(170px); }           
  }

  @keyframes sidemenuanimation2 {
from {transform: translateX(170px);}
to {transform: translateX(0px); }           
  }
```

this is not yielding the result I want

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using an animation, and instead us a transition with a class toggle on the `body` element. (i assume your menu has an id of `menu` in the below css). You can then add a transition to the css to make things "animate".

**CSS**

```
#menu{
    transition:translateX 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transform:translateX(0);
}
.menu-open #menu{
    transform:translateX(170px);
}
```

**JS**

```
if (y >= z) {
    $(body).addClass('menu-open');
    q = 2;
}else if (y < z && q == 2){
    $(body).removeClass('menu-open');
}
```

Comment: changed to: if (y >= z) {
        $(menu1).addClass('menu-open');
        
        
        
    }else if (y < z ){
       $(menu1).removeClass('menu-open');
    }

Comment: and #sidemenu1{
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.9;
    z-index: 30;
    
    transition:translateX 2s ease-in-out;
    transform:translateX(0);
}
.menu-open #sidemenu1{
    transform:translateX(170px);
}

Comment: but nothing happened :(

Comment: add the class to the `body`, otherwise you'll need to use `.menu-open#sidemenu1`